# How do multiple companies collaborate effectively with Microsoft Teams?

Tags: office365, microsoft-teams, collaboration, microsoft365

For example, we have a Team consisting of individuals from 4 companies, each company have potentially multiple domains.

We want the following:

- When we schedule meetings we want to see each other's availability.
- Access to Teams functionality

  - Shared files storage
  - Channels and Conversations
  - Chats and Group Chats

Update 1:

When you are added as a Guest you do not have a Calendar in the toolbar.  You cannot schedule a meeting. This is not good for collaboration. The below image is what it looks like when you are a Guest.
[image: View of MS Teams as Guest]

Update 2:

It appears that this currently is not a supported feature. This really inhibits productivity and collaboration.  [Vote here if you agree](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/37936537-make-calendar-available-for-guest-users).

Comment: You could add people from other organisations as guests in your Teams. Please go through this docs for [guest access in teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/guest-access).

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT if you are added as a guest you cannot even schedule a meeting let alone see others calendars.  Maybe you can use the meet now option, but I've never seen anyone use that effectively in a channel.  People can't just meet on a whim.

Comment: Guest users cannot have the same functionalities as the users in same tenant. Guest users have their own limitations and it is not possible to view a guest users availability while scheduling a meeting.

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT This really inhibits productivity and collaboration.  Vote here if you agree. https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/37936537-make-calendar-available-for-guest-users

Comment: Thanks for raising the uservoice. Sure Will do!

Answer (score 0):

You can add external to your organization people as guests.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/guest-access

Comment: This did not resolve the first bullet point of my question. According to the link, guests do not have visibility to "Calendar, Scheduled Meetings, or Meeting Details".